# Laravel 5 run queue:work for more than one job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have queue:work running every minute.

Laravel 5 queue:work runs only one job at a time.

How can I run 5 jobs every minute?

Comment: run that cli command 5 times in different console windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your app is running on Linux, there are a few ways to do this:

1. Simplest solution: set up **5** `queue:work` process every minute in cron (`crontab -e`):

   ```
   * * * * * php /path/to/your/app/artisan queue:work <queue_driver> --queue=<queue_name> --once
   ```
2. More scalable solution (recommended): use a process manager such as [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to run multiple workers, as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration).
   Configuration example:

   ```
   [program:laravel-worker]
   process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
   command=php /path/to/your/app/artisan queue:work <queue_driver> --queue=<queue_name> --sleep=60 --timeout=90 --tries=3
   autostart=true
   autorestart=true
   user=www-data
   numprocs=5
   redirect_stderr=true
   stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/laravel-worker.stdout.log
   stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/laravel-worker.stderr.log
   ```

Comment: Yes, started using Supervisor.